# bind different size different name dataframes

Tags: r, merge, dataframe, rbind

I have some dataframes with different number of columns and differently named columns which I want to bind together.   I would like to row bind the euro.fix.data dataframe to the euro.prefix.data dataframe.  I imagine this could involve copying the columns and renaming them so the data.frames are consistent, but I am looking for an easier way.  Is there anyway to disregard the naming convention and simply bind if data frames are the same number of columns?

In any case, I cannot even determine how to copy a data frame column without making a hardcoded explicit assignment as many times as I would like the data frame to have columns.

desired out put would be something like:

```
epd <- euro.fix.data[which(euro.fix.data$date >= init.euro.fix.date), ]

df <- data.frame(date = epd$date, DEM.Curncy = epd$EUR.Curncy, ATS.Curncy = epd$EUR.Curncy, BEF.Curncy = epd$EUR.Curncy, NLG.Curncy = epd$EUR.Curncy, FIM.Curncy = epd$EUR.Curncy, FRF.Curncy = epd$EUR.Curncy, IEP.Curncy = epd$EUR.Curncy, ITL.Curncy = epd$EUR.Curncy, PTE.Curncy = epd$EUR.Curncy, ESP.Curncy = epd$EUR.Curncy, DKK.Curncy = epd$EUR.Curncy)

results <- rbind(euro.prefix.data, df)
```

Clearly this is a really bad solution. I am looking for something which could be generalized.
A start would be to simply be able to create a data frame, which is simply on column replicated many times.

Any guidance appreciated.  Thanks.

```
head(euro.prefix.data)
        date DEM.Curncy ATS.Curncy    BEF.Curncy NLG.Curncy FIM.Curncy FRF.Curncy   IEP.Curncy    ITL.Curncy PTE.Curncy
1 1988-12-30  -0.000677  -0.000721 -0.0009014423  -0.000649   0.000090   0.000099 -0.001141827 -0.0004649038   0.000935
2 1989-01-06  -0.000910  -0.000608 -0.0009134615  -0.000830   0.000384  -0.000323 -0.001153846 -0.0004711538   0.000674
3 1989-01-13   0.000109   0.001022 -0.0009134615   0.000205   0.000971   0.000600 -0.001153846 -0.0004711538   0.000660
4 1989-01-20  -0.000990   0.001100 -0.0009134615   0.000060  -0.000029   0.000199 -0.001153846 -0.0004711538   0.002389
5 1989-01-27  -0.000134  -0.001147 -0.0009134615  -0.001331  -0.000989  -0.001459 -0.001153846 -0.0004711538  -0.000821
6 1989-02-03  -0.000133  -0.001151 -0.0010697115  -0.001743  -0.000778   0.000137 -0.001310096 -0.0006197115   0.000695
  ESP.Curncy DKK.Curncy
1  -0.001635  -0.000055
2   0.002641  -0.003195
3   0.003452  -0.001496
4  -0.001926  -0.000402
5   0.001750  -0.001642
6  -0.000844  -0.001076



> head(euro.fix.data[which(euro.fix.data$date >= init.euro.fix.date), ])
          date    EUR.Curncy
105 1999-01-01 -0.0004074215
106 1999-01-08 -0.0003545854
107 1999-01-15 -0.0003652404
108 1999-01-22 -0.0003650181
109 1999-01-29 -0.0003209615
110 1999-02-05 -0.0003106008
```

Comment: thanks @jbaums. as far as I know, at least the way I have been using it, merge() is a join and relies on matching common data values in certain columns (or rows?).  in any case, There are no common data values in the two data frames. its stacking that I am trying to do or a "bind"

Comment: It may help to show what your desired output would look like if a basic merge isn't your goal.

Comment: thanks @cdeterman.  desired results is basically rbind, if the second data frame had the same number of columns as the first, and with the same names.

Comment: I see, you may be after `dplyr::rbind_list`  then, which will fill missing columns with NA.

Comment: Or you could use `library(data.table); rbindlist(list(dat1, dat2), fill=TRUE)`

Comment: I want to put "date" in the second dataframe, under euro.fix.data$date.  That I could accomplish with (merge(..., all =TRUE)) and probably a few other ways. So more importantly I want to put "EUR.Curncy" from the second data frame under each of (DEM.Curncy ATS.Curncy   BEF.Curncy NLG.Curncy FIM.Curncy FRF.Curncy   
IEP.Curncy    ITL.Curncy PTE.Curncy) in the first dataframe.  And I don't even want EUR.Curncy to be in the result, although removing it would be trivial if it was.

Comment: I realized my communication was bad on this so I put a more concrete example of what the results would look like.

Answer (score 0):

Try this... mind you it's a guess because I'm having almost a s much difficulty with your problem presentation as the other commenters:

```
post.fix <- data.frame( date=euro.prefix.data$date, 
                        stack(euro.prefix.data[-1])
```

This shows the structure of the result which obviously is nonsense but shows that you probably need to be preserving the information about which currency is being recorded and that's not something your current problem description seems to be considering. The dates are replicated through R's argument recycling process.

```
> str(data.frame(mpg=mtcars$mpg, stack(mtcars[-1]) ))
'data.frame':   320 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ mpg   : num  21 21 22.8 21.4 18.7 18.1 14.3 24.4 22.8 19.2 ...
 $ values: num  6 6 4 6 8 6 8 4 4 6 ...
 $ ind   : Factor w/ 10 levels "am","carb","cyl",..: 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 ...
```